# List of objects as events from GCS

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We have a bucket where there are 40+ million objects. We would like to read each of these objects extract particular data from a column and store them as separate files.

How to get all these object lists and process each of them? Can we get this list of objects in pub/sub

Comment: 1) When you have a task that processes large numbers of objects and that processing can be done in parallel, use a service like Cloud Dataflow. 2) You can use a service like Pub/Sub to distribute messages, but you will need to write a service to request the object list, parse, and publish to the Pub/Sub topic and another service to process the messages. 3) There are many ways to accomplish this. Research first, test and evaluate, and then post a question when you have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not specified many details so please specified the following .
1.in what language .
2.what type of data to extract and where/how do you want to save/store(if/or any specific file format) them.

meanwhile here is a simple code snippet .

```
exports.iterateThroughFiles = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const bucketName = 'your-bucket-name';
    const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);

    const [files] = await bucket.getFiles();

    files.forEach((file) => {
      // Perform operations on each file
      console.log(`File name: ${file.name}`);
    });

    res.status(200).send('Files iteration completed successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error iterating through files:', error);
    res.status(500).send('An error occurred while iterating through files.');
  }
});
```

if this is it then ok but for any specific approach req. more clarification.

of course you can use pub/sub but

if the task is long running then i will suggest you use [appengine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) or [compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) as the firebase function will not suitable as crossing max time limit